# Удалить некоторые символы в элементе списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужна помощь с удалением лишних символов в элементах списка.

Есть список формата:

```
"['word1', 'https://site.ua/'];27679.0;45986.0;0.6019005784369156;1.4976732048884442;", 
"['word2', 'https://site.ua/'];19929.0;28211.0;0.7064265711956329;1.1931870546949772;", 
"['word3', 'https://site.ua/ua'];10699.0;17985.0;0.5948846260772866;1.3342785654712261;", 
"['word4', 'https://site.ua/'];5860.0;7493.0;0.7820632590417723;1.1664219938609368;"
```

Стоит цикл, который перебирает каждый элемент, нужно добавить проверку, при которой:

```
['word1', 'https://site.ua/']
```

заменялось бы на:

```
word1;https://site.ua/;
```

Понимаю, что скорее всего это делается через регулярки, но додуматься как это реализовать не могу. Максимум до чего дошел, что обрезаю два первых и последних символа, то есть квадратные скобки и одинарные кавычки.

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/0N5TYW

```
import re

print(re.sub(r"\['([^']+)', '([^']+)'\]", r"\1;\2", input()))
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Можно "на пальцах" объяснить как отрабатывает выбор и замена по регулярке?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативное решение с испрльзованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import io
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

data = (
 "['word1', 'https://site.ua/'];27679.0;45986.0;0.6019005784369156;1.4976732048884442;",
 "['word2', 'https://site.ua/'];19929.0;28211.0;0.7064265711956329;1.1931870546949772;",
 "['word3', 'https://site.ua/ua'];10699.0;17985.0;0.5948846260772866;1.3342785654712261;",
 "['word4', 'https://site.ua/'];5860.0;7493.0;0.7820632590417723;1.1664219938609368;")

df = (pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(data)), sep=';', header=None)
        .dropna(axis=1, how="all")
        .add_prefix("val"))

df[["text", "url"]] = df.pop("val0").str.replace(r"[\'\[\]]", "").str.split("\,\s*", expand=True)
```

---

результат:

```
In [212]: df
Out[212]:
      val1     val2      val3      val4   text                 url
0  27679.0  45986.0  0.601901  1.497673  word1    https://site.ua/
1  19929.0  28211.0  0.706427  1.193187  word2    https://site.ua/
2  10699.0  17985.0  0.594885  1.334279  word3  https://site.ua/ua
3   5860.0   7493.0  0.782063  1.166422  word4    https://site.ua/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = "['word1', 'https://site.ua/'];27679.0;45986.0;0.6019005784369156;1.4976732048884442;", "['word2', 'https://site.ua/'];19929.0;28211.0;0.7064265711956329;1.1931870546949772;", "['word3', 'https://site.ua/ua'];10699.0;17985.0;0.5948846260772866;1.3342785654712261;", "['word4', 'https://site.ua/'];5860.0;7493.0;0.7820632590417723;1.1664219938609368;"

spl = res.split(";")
for i in spl:
    word, site = i[0], i[1]
```

Вроде как нужно еще привести в список данные и после чего их вытаскивать. Дебажить надо, сам начинающий)
И дальше перебираешь, заменяешь и обратно в str записываешь. Возможно решение без регулярки.
Решение довольно таки запарное, но как вариант, нужно немного покопаться

Comment: _"Вроде как нужно еще привести в список данные"_ - очень даже нужно.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, спасибо)